# Memory going high while writing data to file in golang

Tags: go

Use case:

1. Read the content from a table in Postgres
2. Process the row Write to a file
3. Write the content to a file

So I have used postgres/sql to read the rows from the table and buffered writer to write the processed row to file. I have also taken care to make sure to flush the buffer at the end of each row so that I can keep control of the memory. But still I can see the memory going as high as 1.5 GB while processing close to 200000 rows.

The code snippet is as below:

```
    r, e := c.Query("select * from tab1")
    if e != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error while query", e.Error())
    }
    c.Close()
    //file is the filehandler for the output file
    fileWriter := bufio.NewWriter(file)
    for r.Next() {
            var res *StatsData = &StatsData{}
            e = sqlstruct.Scan(res, r)
            if e != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Failed to scan", e.Error())
                    continue
            }
            dt := p.CalculateData(*res)
            fileWriter.Write([]byte(dt))
            fileWriter.Flush()
            res = nil
    }
    r.Close()
    file.Close()
```

I expected that since I am flushing the fileWriter at the end of each loop, the buffer will be flushed to the underlying writer which will write the data to the file. Hence the memory usage will be almost constant throughout the operation.

Where am I wrong in my understanding? What can I do more to make sure that the memory can be kept under control?

Comment: Although you are flushing and not keeping the rows in the memory the result of the query which you are storing in 'r' will be all the 200000 rows. I bet if you check you will see memory usage spikes to 1.5GB right after c.Query() line.

Comment: What type is `c`? Why is it closed before reading from `r`?
Also, have you tried putting `res` initialisation outside of the cycle?

Comment: C is the connection object. I didn't try to initialize res outside cycle. My understanding is the res will be garbage collected at the end of the loop.

Comment: Try to define `res` as `var res StatsData` outside of range and call `sqlstruct.Scan(&res, r)`

Comment: Couple things come to mind, the first being you should get in a habit to use defer for the closing of your cursor, connection and file to keep things idiomatic. Second: 1.5 GB for this seems off unless whatever "p" is stores some large result. Is it virtual mem you are looking at perhaps? Also is there a reason you can't pass the reference to CalculateData instead of passing the dereferenced value?

Comment: @Kallol What exactly is "connection object"? If you're using something fancy, it might pull all the data before closing. Try closing `c` after the loop or even better, use `defer` as Corvus Crypto suggested.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. I made the changes as mentioned:
1) Initiated res outside loop
2) Used defer close(c)

But still, the result is not as expected. The query returns 1700000 rows of 22 columns

I tried out a few more checks like I commented out 
p.CalculateData(*res) // This function calculates and writes result into buffer
and can see the memory remaining stable.

This tells me that when I am calculating and writing the result to buffer, the memory is going high. Does Flush() clears up buffer everytime?

Comment: @Kallol Another suggestion: what does `p.CalculateData` return? If it's `string` then it could cause the allocations because `string <-> []byte` conversions almost always copy data.

Comment: Yes. It returns a string and I am converting it to byte while writing to the buffer.Should I use WriteString?